# Making scikit-learn estimator to work differently during training and prediction

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pipeline, gridsearchcv

I am writing an estimator which will be used as a preprocessing step in `scikit-learn` `pipeline`. For that reason I have implemented the `fit()` and `transform()` method. But some preprocessing steps in `transform()` will not be equally applicable when `scikit-learn` will call it during `training` and `prediction`.

More precisely, I want to use this custom estimator to preprocess text data. One of the preprocessing steps is to **correcting the spelling of words**. During training the estimator should find out the tokens in training data and during testing it should correct the **test** data if any spelling mistakes available. It will replace the token of **test** data with the most similar looking token which it has learnt from **train** set. For example: If **train** set has tokens like `apple` or `ornge` and **test** set has tokens `aple` and `orange`. Then, the expected behavior will be when the `transform` method is called during training it should not change anything. But when this same method is called during prediction, it should change `aple` to `apple` and `orange` to `ornge` (i.e, making the tokens similar to the token it saw during training). I want this behavior when this pipeline to be used with `GridSearchCV`.

Following is a draft of the program:

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin

class TextPreprocessor(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self):
        self.le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()


    @staticmethod
    def do_basic_preprocessing(text, is_training):
        # Following is what I want to achieve
        # In other words, I need a way to pass the parameter is_training
        # which will be True or False based on whether the function is 
        # being called during train time or test time (respectively)

        text = preprocessing_1(text)
        text = preprocessing_2(text)
        ............
        ............
        if is_training == False:
            text = preprocessing_exclusively_for_test_time(text)
        ............
        ............
        text = preprocessing_n(text)
 
        return text


    def fit(self, X, y = None):
        if y is not None:
            self.le.fit(y)
        return self


    def transform(self, X, y = None):
        # If transform is called during training
        X = list(map(FeatureExtraction.do_basic_preprocessing(is_training = True), list(X)))
        # Or, if transform is called during testing
        X = list(map(FeatureExtraction.do_basic_preprocessing(is_training = False), list(X)))
        
        y = self.le.transform(y)
        return X, y
```

Comment: I would suggest making `transform` the same and then making `fit` keep the record of words seen. During training, the `TextPreprocessor` will immediately add training examples to training data memory and then transform it (not replace any words since its being added during the `fit` call). Then `transform` gets to be agnostic.

Comment: @zcoleman if I am not mistaken, your idea is: keep a record of all words which it gets during `fit()` call. As `fit()` only gets called when training happens. Therefore, if any new unseen words found we can safely assume that it must be from test set, as it is not found in the record, right? You can post your idea as an answer.

Comment: Yes that is the idea! Having to work in this way is compounded by the fact that you are want to use it in a pipeline which calls the methods for you. During `Pipeline.fit` the transforms will call `fit` and then `transform` see here: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html#:~:text=Fit%20all%20the%20transformers%20one%20after%20the%20other%20and%20transform%20the%20data.

Comment: This unfortunately is not necessarily an answer to your exact question, so I feel the comment is more appropriate. I don't believe this is actually possible to track the state of "training" vs "eval" in sklearn today.